# Get one record per GROUP given an ORDER

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a simple table:

```
+--------------------------+
|       `actions`          |
+----+--------+------------+
| id | person | time       |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  | Mark   | 22:00      |
+----+--------+------------+
| 2  | Paul   | 19:00      |
+----+--------+------------+
| 3  | Mark   | 17:00      |
+----+--------+------------+
| 4  | Paul   | 08:00      |
+----+--------+------------+
| 5  | Paul   | 23:00      |
+----+--------+------------+
```

I want to perform a query that **groups** by the `person` column, then returns the `id` of only the earliest `time`.  So the result should look something like:

```
+----+--------+------------+
| 3  | Mark   | 17:00      |
+----+--------+------------+
| 4  | Paul   | 08:00      |
+----+--------+------------+
```

I don't think this is a difficult query, but for some reason I simply cannot get it.

Comment: What is datatype for `time` column ?

Comment: I already answered my own question below.  For my real-life example it was datetime.  I just showed the time for this example to simplify it, figuring it was sufficient enough to convey the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

`SELECT id, person, MIN(time) FROM actions GROUP BY person;`

Change `MIN` to `MAX` to grab only the largest.